# Lucene 4.0 - HighFreqTerms class how to get actual string of Term

Tags: lucene, indexing, search-engine, information-retrieval

i want to get the highest frequency Terms of a Lucene Index.

i use:

```
HighFreqTerms.getHighFreqTerms(reader, noOfTerms, field);
```

The Problem is, the function has a return Type of "TermStats[]". The class TermStats has a field called "termText" but the type of that field is not String but "ByteRef" - How can i get a String representation of my high frequency Terms?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call the method termText.utf8ToString().